# How to place text on same height as image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move the h3s and paragraphs on this page to where the h3 is level with the top of the image rather than slightly below the top line of the image if that makes sense. I just managed to be able to get the text next to the pictures the way I wanted them, but now I just need to get this fixed.

Code:

```css
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: aquilinetworegular;
  color: #000066;
  font-size: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  left: 20px;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 200%
}

h3 {
  font-size: 200%
}

p.tagline {
  position: absolute;
  color: #800000;
  top: 80px;
  left: 12px;
  font-size: 19px;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

p {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.washington {
  float: right;
}

.washington img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.greene {
  float: right;
}

.greene img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.knox {
  float: right;
}

.knox img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.wayne {
  float: right;
}

.wayne img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.arnold {
  float: right;
}

.arnold img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.steuben {
  float: right;
}

.steuben img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.marion {
  float: right;
}

.marion img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.kosciuszko {
  float: right;
}

.kosciuszko img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.morgan {
  float: right;
}

.morgan img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.tallmadge {
  float: right;
}

.tallmadge img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.hamilton {
  float: right;
}

.hamilton img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.moultrie {
  float: right;
}

.moultrie img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.laurens {
  float: right;
}

.laurens img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.lafayette {
  float: right;
}

.lafayette img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.rochambeau {
  float: right;
}

.rochambeau img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.chastellux {
  float: right;
}

.chastellux img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.knyphausen {
  float: right;
}

.knyphausen img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.rall {
  float: right;
}

.rall img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.clinton {
  float: right;
}

.clinton img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.cornwallis {
  float: right;
}

.cornwallis img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.howe {
  float: right;
}

.howe img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.gage {
  float: right;
}

.gage img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.burgoyne {
  float: right;
}

.burgoyne img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.andre {
  float: right;
}

.andre img {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.northerncampaign {
  margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.northerncampaign img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.southerncampaign {
  margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.southerncampaign img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.image-center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.image-center2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.imagecenter3 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.imagecenter4 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.imagecenter6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

form {
  float: right;
}


/* Navbar container */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  font-family: Arial;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The dropdown container */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Dropdown button */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}


/* Add a red background color to navbar links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: blue;
}


/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Soldiers of Columbia</h1>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p class="tagline">A research site about the American Revolutionary War</p>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." required>
  <input type="button" value="Search">
</form>
<br>
<br>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/90/The_March_to_Valley_Forge_William_Trego.png" width=1350 height=350>
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="causes.html">Causes</a>
    <a href="amrevbattles.html">Battles</a>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Armies<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
     </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="continentalforces.html">Continental</a>
        <a href="britishforces.html">British</a>
        <a href="frenchforces.html">French</a>
        <a href="hessianforces.html">Hessian</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Commanders<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="americancommanders.html">American</a>
        <a href="britishcommanders.html">British</a>
        <a href="frenchcommanders.html">French</a>
        <a href="hessiancommanders.html">Hessian</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Battles of the American Revolutionary War</h2>
<div class="northerncampaign">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/U.S._Army_-_Artillery_Retreat_from_Long_Island_1776.jpg" width=350 height 300>
  <a href="northerncampaign.html">
    <h3>Northern theater</h3>
  </a>
  <p>Read about the battles of the war's northern theater</p>
</div>
<div class="southerncampaign">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/KingsMountain_DeathOfFerguson_Chappel.jpg" width=350 height=300>
  <a href="southerncampaign.html">
    <h3>Southern theater</h3>
  </a>
  <p>Read about the battles of the war's southern theater</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean **Northern theater** and **Southern theater** section only?

Comment: Yes, I want to move the text up to where the h3s are level with the tops of the pics

Answer (score 1):

This is because the h3 `line-height` and `margin` getting pushed down so if you add `h3 {margin: 0; line-height: 1;}` the text will align with the top of the image. and you change the values.

Check this code:

```css
.northerncampaign {
  margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.northerncampaign img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

.southerncampaign {
  margin: 0 0 15px 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
}

.southerncampaign img {
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
}

h3 {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="northerncampaign">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/U.S._Army_-_Artillery_Retreat_from_Long_Island_1776.jpg" width=350 height 300>
  <a href="northerncampaign.html">
    <h3>Northern theater</h3>
  </a>
  <p>Read about the battles of the war's northern theater</p>
</div>
<div class="southerncampaign">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/KingsMountain_DeathOfFerguson_Chappel.jpg" width=350 height=300>
  <a href="southerncampaign.html">
    <h3>Southern theater</h3>
  </a>
  <p>Read about the battles of the war's southern theater</p>
</div>
```